# Errors During R Notebook Compilation

Tags: r

How to resolve the following errors occurring when compiling/knitting R Notebook into a document? All the required packages are successfully loaded, still, the issue persists.

I restarted RStudio several times. Loaded all the necessary packages. Explored several websites for the resolution, but in vain.

Code:

```
# pipe operator
x<-5:15
mean(x)
x%>%mean

sum(z,na.rm=TRUE)
z%>%sum(na.rm=TRUE)

sum(is.na(z))
z%>%is.na%>%sum

mean(is.na(z))
z%>%is.na%>%mean
```

Output:

```
|...................................                 |  67% (unnamed-chunk-1)

processing file: qwerty.Rmd
Quitting from lines 13-124 (qwerty.Rmd) 
Error in x %>% mean : could not find function "%>%"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
                                                                                                            
Execution halted
```

Code:

```
data(diamonds)
View(diamonds)

# base histogram(s)
hist(x=diamonds$carat,main="FREQUENCY vs. CARAT",xlab="carat",ylab="frequency")

# base scatter plot(s)
(plot(x=diamonds$carat,y=diamonds$price,xlab="carat",ylab="price"))
```

Output:

```
 |...................................                 |  67% (unnamed-chunk-1)

processing file: qwerty.Rmd
                                                                                                            
Quitting from lines 13-24 (qwerty.Rmd) 
Error in as.data.frame(x) : object 'diamonds' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> View -> as.data.frame
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is "Error in x %>% mean : could not find function "%>%""
Try to add library(tidyverse) before this code (you need to load all the required packages in the .Rmd file so it can knit)
Also, you will be able to use the diamonds dataset

Hope this can help you!